# Javascript - is it possible to access an array like var b = 'opt' + 5; alert(b[61]);?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, construction

In PHP, I can do something like:

```
$name = "options{$a}"; // or "options" . $a, doesn't matter

for ($i = 0; $i < count($name[$i]); $i++) {
    // do something...
}
```

as long as **options0** exists (assuming **$a** is **0**, or **1**, or whatever), this construction is perfectly valid, but... now I need to do the same in Javascript, but without success for now.

Can anyone tell me how can it be done?

Comment: You can do this with "global" variables on the `window` object, but not local variables declared with `var`.  I would consider this to be bad practice anyway, even in PHP, when you have a wonderful data structure called an `array` available to you.

Comment: It might be an idea to learn about arrays

Comment: What do you mean "as long as options0 exists"? If `$a` is `0` then `$name = "options{$a}";` will result in `$name` being the **string** `options0` not a variable that may exist by the names of either `$options0` or `$options[0]` if that's indeed what you're expecting.

Comment: now is a good time to learn how to use arrays instead of learning how to do such abominations. a programmer who isnt fluent with arrays, is a programmer who will struggle forever.

Answer (score 2):

You can use arrays as some of the comments have described, or you can use object properties. They involve similar notation, but work differently. For instance, you could do something like this:

```
var options = { option0 : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                option1 : ['d', 'e'],
                ...
               };
var a = 0;
var count = options['option' + a].length; // assigns 3 to count
```

This access the property of `options` named `'option' + a` (or, with this sample code, `option0`).

While you can easily compute and use property names, you cannot (as also pointed out in the comments) do this with local variable names.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I admit my explanation has been very poor, and I apologize for that. I need this 'trickery' because I want to replace OpenCart use of autocomplete text fields (now THAT is abominable) for a selector (which is more appropiate) for displaying different product options and their values.

The problem is I'm loading the option selector with PHP and now I must know which option id does a certain selector belongs to before actually loading the option values in a second selector.

Comment: @JulioMecaHansen - Why won't my suggested structure work for that? Following the patter that I posted, the first selector index can be used to retrieve the array of options needed for the second selector. What am I missing?

Comment: It worked :) Although, in the end, I ended 'encoding' the values I needed with a delimiter. It produced an alternate solution, but hey, yours worked, plus it's what I initially looked for in the beginning. Thanks :)